# CSS middle image

Tags: css, center, vertical-alignment

Here is my code.
Please help to make it centering middle
and also, all images size is not the same

***CSS:***

```
body {
   margin: 0px;
}

.wrapper {
   text-align:center;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 21
}

.wrapper img {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

***HTML:***

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://static.desktopnexus.com/thumbnails/196734-bigthumbnail.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: I'm almost positive that most elements that have `inline-block` as their default display properties (images, form fields) cannot be set to `table-cell`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the margin on the image.

```
.wrapper img {
    margin: auto;
}
```

This method can be used in any objects but make sure the parent has a width or height set.

Comment: This only covers horizontal alignment, not vertical.

Comment: That's because the wrapper fits the height of the image. If that's not the case, it'll work fine.